# jQuery sticky dialog modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

With the new Cookie regulation, like all of us I need to display a message to the user informing them of the cookie I hold on the site. I've did some research and the best example I've seen is on http://www.packtpub.com.

I have jQuery on my site but no means i know how much of it works. I was wondering if someone can shed some light on how I can implement a similar solution. I've tired to work out how its done on packtpub.com but its a bit over my head. I've searched for modals and sticky modals but ive not found a good example of how i can produce a similar solution as most dialog modals seem to work like by greying out the background until some action is performed on the modal.

I would appreciate any useful tips anyone may have in how i can recreate a similar solution.

thank you.

Comment: [Default demo here doesn't](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default)? And technically it's not a modal unless it's blocking it's parent. You're wanting a non-blocking (non-modal) dialog. Which may explain why you can't find what you're looking for.

Comment: Checkout jGrowl with option sticky if that would suffice your requirement. Google for sticky jGrowl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an element with your contents,

```
<div id="cookie-notification">
    <!-- Your content goes here !-->
    <a href="#" id="close-notifiction">Close for now</a>
    <a href="#" id="close-notifiction-forever">Never show again</a>
</div>
```

Use css to position it fixed at bottom, and a big z-index to take it to the top of others.

```
#cookie-notification{
    position : fixed;
    bottom : 10px;
    right : 10px;
    z-index : 99999;
    //more of your styles ..
    }
```

Now you have the Notification at bottom right of your page.

Now to hide it with jQuery.

```
$('#close-notification').click(function(){
    $('#cookie-notification').fadeOut(300);
    return false;
    }
```

To 'do not show this again', set your cookie to never show this again, check if this cookie is set when page loads, and hide the noification if that's the case.

```
$('#close-notification').click(function(){
    $('#cookie-notification').fadeOut(300);
    createCookie('show-notification','never',9999); 
    //refer the link below and use the code from there to make create cookie work
    return false;
    }
```

//check if cookie is set when page loads

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(readCookie('show-notification') == 'never'){
            $('#cookie-notification').hide();
            }
    }
```

Here is a cookie code at bottom of this page http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Thank you for this, i wasn't expecting a full on solution :) i've now implemented this and making tweaks. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @david-l I just wanted to prevent you from using plugins for this.